# spacing disappears on posts when importing

Tags: themes

This is a random question, so I'll be lucky if there's an answer out there.

I imported this wp site from another location, and for some reason, none of the posts show spacing between paragraphs anymore. If you look at any post, you'll see there is no space between each paragraph. In the actual post, on the backend, the spaces are all there. Each paragraph has a nice space between it. On the actual site, the spacing disappears. What gives?

This is the case with all of her posts, so I'd be just delighted if there is some solution to the issue.

it's at: www.travelwithcastle.com and it's a twentytwelve child theme

Kelly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Sven noted in the comment, your theme doesn't have any spacing after paragraphs. It's actually set to no space between paragraphs on line 797 of your style.css. If you were to change that line and the one above it so the last numbers in each line were 10px and 1rem, you'd have fairly default spacing back.

The spacing in the admin is controlled by a different stylesheet, likely the default one in your case.